# Error al crear usuario con devise desde otro controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Quiero que mi admin pueda crear usuarios de diferentes roles cosa que no hace mi vista normal de registro, pero el validate por defecto de devise me da error antes de que entre a la página.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi controller admin es:

admin_controller.rb

```
    class AdminController < ApplicationController
          before_action :authenticate_user!
      def index

        request_hash = {
          :name => params[:name],
          :email => params[:email],
          :role => params[:role],
          :password => params[:password],
          :password_confirmation => params[:password_confirmation]
        }

        @user = User.create!(request_hash)
        @user.save
      end
  end
```

Aplicacion_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?



   def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
     session[:previous_url] ||
     if current_user.role == "admin"
       admin_index_path
     else
       jolex_index_path
     end

   end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name, :role])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name, :country])
  end


end
```

Model: User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
  :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

view: index.html.erb //es solo por ahora después sera otra ruta

```
<%= form_for resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name) do |f|  %>

                  <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :name %><br />
                    <%= f.text_field :name %>
                  </div>

                  <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :email %><br />
                    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
                  </div>

                  <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :password %>
                    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
                    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
                    <% end %><br />
                    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
                  </div>

                  <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
                    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
                  </div>

                    <div class="field">

                      <%= f.select(:role) do %>
                        <% [['Admin', "admin"], ['User', "user"]].each do |c| -%>
                          <%= content_tag(:option, c.first, value: c.last) %>
                        <% end %>
                      <% end %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="actions">
                        <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
                    </div>
                  <% end %>
```

Quisiera saber si estoy por el camino correcto o si hay mejores formas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se debe a que estás creando un usuario en la acción `index`, la cual (seguramente) es una ruta `GET` a la que no envías parámetros (como muestras en la imagen y puedes confirmar en los logs); `index`, de acuerdo a tu código, presenta la forma para crear el usuario.

`request_hash` y `User.create!(request_hash) deben ir en la acción`create` (en caso que estés siguiendo REST), la cual recibirá los parámetros que envíes (por ahora) desde *index.html.erb*.

Tu acción `index` debería tener únicamente la creación de un objeto `User` que será utilizado al crear la forma en la vista, por ejemplo:

**Controlador**

```
def index
  @user = User.new
end
```

**Vista (*index.html.erb*)**

```
<%= form_for @user, as: resource_name do |f|  %>
  <!-- Campos de la forma -->
<% end %>
```

Comment: NoMethodError in Admin#index es lo que me dice tal vez tiene que ver con que yo no tengo user_controller si no uso el aplicacion_helper para hacer login en otros lados?

Comment: @J.leo ¿Podrías mostrar el log completo?

Comment: https://framapic.org/8vVQjLSB1jSm/ljl5VPfd2LFH.jpg aqui esta el error

Comment: <%= form_for @user, as: resource_name, url: admin_index_path do |f|  %> es la solucion en el form muchas muchas gracias por tu ayuda